# Creating a directive with a dynamic ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

Okay, so here's my custom directive:

```
angular.module('bulwarkWebControls', [])
.directive('dropdownList', [
    function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                label: '@', // optional
                changeCallback: '&',
                options: '=',
                required: "=",
                disabled: "=",
                id: "=",
                name: "=",
                model: "=",
                value: "=",
                display: "="
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true, // optional 
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/dropDownList.html',
            link: {
                pre: function (scope, element, attr) {
                     scope.expression = "o."+value +" as o."+display+" for o in options";
                }

            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Template:

```
<div class="row form-group form-horizontal">
<label data-for="id" class="control-label col-md-3">{{label}}</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select data-id="id" data-name="name" data-ng-disabled="disabled" class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="model"
            data-ng-options="{{expression}}" data-ng-required="required">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Html code that utilizes the directive:

```
            <div>
            <dropdown-list data-label="Phone(s)" data-id="phoneList" data-name="phoneList"
                           data-disabled="vm.workOrder.Contacted"
                           data-model="vm.workOrder.PhoneNumber_Id" data-value="Id" data-display="Number"
                           data-options="vm.workOrder.CustomerPhoneNumbers" data-required="vm.workOrder.SpokeTo_Id!=5" />
        </div>
```

What I am trying to do is basically create the expression for the ng-options dynamically at run-time based on the "display" and "value" parameters that I am passing to the directive. You can see that in the "pre:" linking function inside the directive. Now, I know that this is not working because at the time this function is being executed I do not have the scope values. However, I cannot do this in the post: linking because that would be too late for the ng-options expression. Is there a way to achieve this functionality or am I totally barking up the wrong tree here? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I used the following code in the template:

```
<div class="row form-group form-horizontal">
<label data-for="id" class="control-label col-md-3">{{label}}</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select data-id="id" data-name="name" data-ng-disabled="disabled" class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="model"
            data-ng-options="o.{{value}} as o.{{display}} for o in options" data-ng-required="required" compile>
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

That, and I took whatever code I had originally put in the pre: linking function inside the directive.